# Inheritance - Access base classes attribute

Tags: python

I created 2 `classes`, `Result` is the base for `AdditionResult`. What did I miss to access the base classes attribute (`results`) ?

```
import sys
class Result:
    CATEGORY = 'foo'

    def __init__(self):
        self.results = {}


class AdditionResult(Result):
    CATEGORY = 'addition'

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Result, self).__init__()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

        # debug
        print(self.__class__)
        print(self.__class__.__base__)
        print(self.__dict__)

    def calculate(self):
        self.results[AdditionResult.CATEGORY] = self.a + self.b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.version)
    sr = AdditionResult(3, 8)
    sr.calculate()
```

Result is:

```
3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
<class '__main__.AdditionResult'>
<class '__main__.Result'>
{'a': 3, 'b': 8}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\i.py", line 29, in <module>
    sr.calculate()
  File "C:\temp\i.py", line 23, in calculate
    self.results[AdditionResult.CATEGORY] = self.a + self.b
AttributeError: 'AdditionResult' object has no attribute 'results'
```

I expected to be able access self.results

Comment: You never called `Result.__init__`; it's `super(AdditionResult, self).__init__()` or just `super().__init__()`. Your call to `super` jumped straight to `object.__init__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

You broke the super call : you're calling `Result.__init__` because
`super(Result, self).__init__()` means :

> call the parent class of `Result` with instance `self`

---

#### Fix

What you want is the parent of `AdditionResult` so `super(AdditionResult, self).__init__()`

---

#### Improve

Use the empty argument version

```
class AdditionResult(Result):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__()
```